# OpenCV 2.3.1. cv::Mat to std::vector cast

Tags: c++, opencv

I do have a trouble converting cv::Mat to std::vector:

```
cv::Mat m = cv::Mat_<int>::eye(3, 3);    
std::vector<int> vec = m;
```

gives me the following:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dims == 2 && (size[0] == 1 || size[1] == 1 || size[0]*size[1] == 0)) in create, file /build/buildd-opencv_2.3.1-11-i386-tZNeKk/opencv-2.3.1/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 1225
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /build/buildd-opencv_2.3.1-11-i386-tZNeKk/opencv-2.3.1/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:1225: error: (-215) dims == 2 && (size[0] == 1 || size[1] == 1 || size[0]*size[1] == 0) in function create
```

from mat.hpp:

```
template<typename _Tp> inline Mat::operator vector<_Tp>() const
{
    vector<_Tp> v;
    copyTo(v);
    return v;
}
```

and later on the following code in copyTo is executed:

```
//mat.hpp 
template<typename _Tp> inline _OutputArray::_OutputArray(vector<_Tp>& vec) : _InputArray(vec) {}

template<typename _Tp> inline _InputArray::_InputArray(const vector<_Tp>& vec)
    : flags(STD_VECTOR + DataType<_Tp>::type), obj((void*)&vec) {}

// operations.hpp
template<typename _Tp> inline Size_<_Tp>::Size_()
    : width(0), height(0) {}
```

and then I get an exceptions.

Any idea? Is it a bug? Probably, I do not understand something...
Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to convert a two-dimensional 3x3 matrix into a one-dimensional vector. Not sure what result you're expecting from that, but you probably want to convert a **row** of the matrix into a vector. You can use this by giving the vector constructor a pointer to the row data:

```
int *p = eye.ptr<int>(0); // pointer to row 0
std::vector<int> vec(p, p+eye.cols); // construct a vector using pointer
```

Comment: I want to put rows of a matrix in a single vector. If you are familiar with Octave/Matlab this one can be done as m(:)

Comment: Very well then! It is not possible to do so with a whole matrix. Then I should loop over all the rows. Thank You anyway!

Comment: Not sure if OpenCV has that functionality, but you could always do it yourself. Saving one row/col at a time (and maybe combining them afterwards) sounds like a plan!

Answer (score 1):

Very Well Then!

cv::Mat is stored as an array of bytes! 
So, if You want to represent your matrix as vector, You may do something like this:

```
cv::Mat m = cv::Mat_<int>::eye(3, 3);
int* data = reinterpret_cast<int*>(m.data);
int len = m.rows * m.cols;
std::vector<int> vec(len);
std::copy(data + 0, data + len, vec.begin());
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it looks like you can only convert matrices where one dimension is 1 to `std::vector`, i.e. only row or column vectors (mathematically speaking):

`dims == 2 && (size[0] == 1 || size[1] == 1)`

Which kind of makes sense...

Comment: I do understand. But I think it is strange not allowing to represent matrix as a single vector. Such representation is very useful in practice! =)